# Fraction appears small on the left side of the equation and large on the right side

Tags: equations, align

As you can see in the picture the fraction appears small on the left side of the equation and large on the right side.[image]

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{marvosym} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}  
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\sisetup{locale = DE} 
\usepackage[intlimits]{empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{theorem} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{array}
\tolerance=2000 
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{20pt} %verhindert das herrausragen von Wörtern übers Zeilenende

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\log v_0&=\log k_R + \alpha \cdot \log [\ce{I}]_0 \\
$\rz{I}){ }$\log 8,70\cdot 10^{-4}\frac{mol}{dm^3 s} &= \log k_R + \alpha\cdot\log  1\cdot 10^{-5}\frac{mol}{dm^3}\\
$\rz{II}){ }$\log 3,48\cdot 10^{-3}\frac{mol}{dm^3 s} &= \log k_R + \alpha\cdot\log 2\cdot 10^{-5}\frac{mol}{dm^3}\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

You guys have an idea why that happens and how I can make both small? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! How many error messages do you get when you compile this? You shouldn't use `$`s inside the `align` environment. (But this is just the tip of the iceberg.)

Comment: What is the `\rz` command?

Comment: ***\rz*** makes Roman numbers.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, you’re right! I just removed the `$`and all the errors (that I didn't payed attention before, since the document got so long) are gone, and the fractions are all the same size now. Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Schrödinger's cat has pointed out, the problem lies with the `$` inside the `align` environment.

```
\begin{align*}
    \log v_0&=\log k_R + \alpha \cdot \log \text{[Ar]}_0 \\
    \text{I)}\log 8,70\cdot 10^{-4}\frac{mol}{dm^3 s} &= \log k_R + \alpha\cdot\log  1\cdot 10^{-5}\frac{mol}{dm^3}\\
    \text{II)}\log 3,48\cdot 10^{-3}\frac{mol}{dm^3 s} &= \log k_R + \alpha\cdot\log 2\cdot 10^{-5}\frac{mol}{dm^3}\\
\end{align*}
```

Produces the desired output:

[image]

Whereas

```
\begin{align*}
    \log v_0&=\log k_R + \alpha \cdot \log \text{[Ar]}_0 \\
    $\text{I)}$\log 8,70\cdot 10^{-4}\frac{mol}{dm^3 s} &= \log k_R + \alpha\cdot\log  1\cdot 10^{-5}\frac{mol}{dm^3}\\
    $\text{II)}$\log 3,48\cdot 10^{-3}\frac{mol}{dm^3 s} &= \log k_R + \alpha\cdot\log 2\cdot 10^{-5}\frac{mol}{dm^3}\\
\end{align*}
```

reproduces your problem:

[image]

Note:
I replaced `\rz` and `\ce` in your code with `\text{...}` to get your example working on my side.

Comment: mol dm etc shouldn't be set in math italic

Answer (score 2):

Since you load `siunits`, why not use the much simpler `\SI` command to typeset numbers with units.  I removed the `*$` inside `align*`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\sisetup{locale = DE}
\usepackage[intlimits]{empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{array}
\tolerance=2000
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{20pt} %verhindert das herrausragen von Wörtern übers Zeilenende

\begin{document}

\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}
\begin{align*}
\log v_0&=\log k_R + \alpha \cdot \log [\ce{I}]_0 \\
\mathrm{I})\;\log\SI{8.70e-4}{\mol\per\dm\cubed\per\s}&= \log k_R + \alpha\cdot \log\SI{1e-5}{\mol\per \dm\cubed\per\s}\\[1ex]
 \mathrm{II})\;\log \SI{3.48 e-3}{\mol\per \dm\cubed\per\s} &= \log k_R + \alpha\cdot\log \SI{2e-5}{\mol\per \dm\cubed\per\s}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This loads a lot of unnecessary stuff.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: I didn't try to simplify  the O.P.'s preamble, except for removing àmsmath` since `empheq` is loaded.

Comment: @Bernard: Thank you! I just replaced the `$*` with `\mathrm{*}` like you did and it works. So i don't even need the `\SI` function.